# Are there Android phones that cannot be used for app development?

Tags: android

Is it true that ANY Android phone can be used for App development and testing?

I'm trying to find some inexpensive off-contract hardware for development and testing of our Apps. I've found some devices I can buy New with No Contract for $150 to $300 (like the HTC Aria or the Huawei Ascend). Is there anything that would prevent me from using these devices for USB debugging and app testing? I guess I'm concerned because  I've read how the HTC Aria has been locked down by AT&T to limit applications. I suspect this won't affect me loading apps using ADB, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use any phone for testing applications via the Android development tools. This includes the HTC Aria of what I've read.
You can read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

And it is not true what Sam Dufel wrote. A developer phone have messaging and phone features. It's just as any other ordinary unlocked phone. The only difference between the dev-phones is that they have unlocked bootloaders so you can install and customize your own Android-system and install it. It is rooted by default.

Comment: I read Sam's comment to mean you had to buy messaging/phone features elsewhere. I didn't think he meant you couldn't use the phone.

Comment: Some phones are certainly more developer friendly than others. I just tried to use a Samsung Galaxy S. Unfortunately, it requires special USB drivers that are included as part of the Samsung Kies PC software. I couldn't find a US download (no idea why) but the UK download includes the US versions of Kies and the USB drivers. See http://www.samsungmobile.co.uk/support/samsung-mobile-manuals.do.

Answer (score 0):

Google actually sells development phones - after you create a developer account, they give you an option to buy one of a couple different models.  You don't get any messaging / phone features though, obviously.

Comment: yes, I know. we have Nexus Ones purchased through that program. But, I'm looking for more devices, a variety of devices, and ways of saving money.

Comment: Pop in an activated SIM card into one of these phones and you get messaging/phone features just like with any other phone.  Why would you think otherwise?